# Adding a watermark to an m4s video segment

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, watermark

I have video file (mp4, h264), which divided on m4s segments for streaming video on website. When user requesting some segment I want to add to a file watermark with his id. Is that possible with standard libraries or soft?

I would be grateful for any help

I tried to use ffmpeg and moviepy, but unfortunately this works great with mp4 file, but doesn't work with segments.

Comment: You would need to do just in time encoding on every segment and cache them

Comment: sorry, i'm very new in this. I thought it works in another way. 
Could you give me an example of library or app which can do it? Maybe you know some reliable solutions

Comment: It seems ffmpeg can do it all. thanks for the direction

Comment: @Azamat What do you mean by "file watermark"... Is it supposed to be hidden somewhere in the file bytes or is it supposed to be visible as pixels on the screen? Also if pixels, then do they have to be easily readable (big letters)? or is it enough to just have a small area with pixels that represents the user ID (maybe similar to QR code or such ID pattern or graphic)? The pattern part is doable without re-encoding. Basically you either add custom keyframes (using raw YUV pixels, not RGB) which has user ID text. Option 2 is replace some macroblocks (frame area) with custom pre-encoded ID one

Comment: @Azamat PS: Do you (or someone in your team) have good experience working with bytes (searching, writing, bit-shifting, bit-masking, etc)? If yes I can experiment with some possibilities and later can advise. Otherwise stick with FFmpeg re-encoding if that is working okay for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

@azamat If you just want to add a small area with pixels that represent the identities (image/text), watermarking Library or API can help to implement this functionality.

[Here's a blog post](https://apyhub.com/blog/top-tools-to-watermark-videos) my team at ApyHub precisely wrote to address the video watermarking techniques and their benefits. ( It does include `ffmpeg` and `moviepy` as well. )

I'm currently a dev advocate @ApyHub and part of my job is to make developers succeed. Let me know if you face the issue again.